# Mount ISO to burn

Tags: windows, optical-media, iso

My current workflow is as follows:

Windows Media Player => Burn to phyiscal CD => Create ISO from physical CD.

My only need is the ISO. The above is slow and costs me physical media.

What (free) tool is available that would allow me to mount an ISO such that I may burn to it from other applications such as Windows Media Player as if it were a blank CD in a physical drive?

Comment: FormatFactory ?

Comment: @user1917769 I want to use WMP's encoder to be consistent with the rest of my collection.

Comment: What is on the CD from Media Player? If you are making a audio CDs from MP3s, etc and then converting to an ISO, you'll still need something to do the format conversion, etc. before creating the ISO image.

Comment: @ivanivan WMP does the conversion from MP3 to CDA when burning as an audio CD.